# average of the 75% shorter by month DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to have the average value on my 75% shorter processing time by month.

for that I have created a measure  to define how much entry represents this 75% of the shortest and it look like this :

```
75% shortest = rounddown(count('data'[col1])*75/100,0)
```

And this is working.

After that I calculate the average of my value with this:

```
average = calculate(Average('data'[value]), TOPN(75% shortest,'data','data'[value],ASC))
```

and that give me the average of my value on the 75% shortest but its on all my data and what I would like is for it to take 75% of the most shorter of each month and not 75% of the total.

[image]

Below  an exemple of my input. I use the ID for the count fonction.
with my method i found 1.52 but if i take the 75 shorter month by month i should find 2.42.

How  I want the calculation work :

[image]

In this picture we can see how the data are treated and how I would like it to be.

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output ?

Comment: hello i add it in an edit of the topic